# Type inference error

Tags: f#, stdin

I have two types:

```
type Issue = {
  Id: string;
  Assigned_To: string;
}

type Journal = {
  JournalizedId: string;
  Id: string;
  UserId: string;
}
```

I want to create a function which get the list of Issue's and Id and return the Assigned_To field of the first element in the list with Id:

```
let assignedToOfIssueById (id: string) (issues: Issue list): string =
  let issue = List.filter (fun i -> i.Id = id) issues |> List.head
  issue.Assigned_To
```

I get error

```
    let issue = List.filter (fun i -> i.Id = id) issues |> List.head
  -----------------------------------------------^^^^^^

/Users/demas/stdin(14,48): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    Journal list    
but given a
    Issue list    
The type 'Journal' does not match the type 'Issue'
```

Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression:

```
List.filter (fun i -> i.Id = id) issues
```

from `fun` usage `i` is infered as `Journal` (it is the last type declaration that contains `Id` member). You can play around:

1. Change `Journal.Id` to `Id2` and it will work,
2. Change the order of `Journal` and `Issue`... and it will work.

To fix it, change this function to (explicitly providng the type):

```
let assignedToOfIssueById2 (id : string) (issues : Issue list) : string =
  let issue = List.filter (fun (i : Issue) -> i.Id = id) issues |> List.head
  issue.Assigned_To
```

or better (let `filter` infer the correct type from the list itself):

```
let assignedToOfIssueById2 (id : string) (issues : Issue list) : string =
  let issue = issues |> List.filter (fun i -> i.Id = id) |> List.head
  issue.Assigned_To
```